# How to link DLL to Visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, dll, hid

This seems like a very common issue and it serves no need for a new question, but a lot of the support I've seen online is for visual studio. I know I have to modify my task.json and be careful with my folder structure, but I am still not sure the exact steps to take to ensure I am linking the library correctly. I have the dll file as you'll see in the file structure image below, but I don't know how to link it in vscode.
Here's my main c++ file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <HTUSB.h>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned short  WORD; // 2bytes

int main() {

WORD wPID = 0x04D9;     
WORD wVID = 0xE000;     
unsigned char pCmd[7]={0x02,0x41,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x03};
unsigned char pBuf[32];

//send command
HTUSB_Close();
if(HTUSB_Open(wPID, wVID) != 0) {
    return false;
}
else {
    if(HTUSB_SetTimeouts(500, 500 )!= HT_SUCCESS) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        HTUSB_WriteCmd(7, pCmd);
    }
}

//receive data
HTUSB_ReadData(32, pBuf);

HTUSB_Close();

return 0;
}
```

It's called decibel_test.cpp. The problem is with the HTUSB.H. I need some help in figuring out how to modify the tasks.json file below:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
    }
]
}
```

Here's the HTUSB.H file if that helps. It has compiler errors for the HTUSB methods because it's not being linked to the DLL correctly. Here's the HTUSB.H file below:

```
    /********************************************************************
    created:    2011/06/29
    filename:   HTUSB.h
    file base:  HTUSB DLL
    file ext:   h
    author:     Bill
    
    purpose:    Exported function declartion
*********************************************************************/



#ifndef __HTUSB_H__
#define __HTUSB_H__

// The following ifdef block is the standard way of creating macros which make exporting 
// from a DLL simpler. All files within this DLL are compiled with the HIDDLL_EXPORTS
// symbol defined on the command line. this symbol should not be defined on any project
// that uses this DLL. This way any other project whose source files include this file see 
// HIDDLL_API functions as being imported from a DLL, wheras this DLL sees symbols
// defined with this macro as being exported.
#ifdef HIDDLL_EXPORTS
#define HIDDLL_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)     
#else
#define HIDDLL_API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)     
#endif

#ifdef USE_HIDDLL_LIB

    #pragma message("Automatically linking with HTUSBee.lib")

    #ifdef _DEBUG
        #pragma comment (lib, "Debug/HTUSB.Lib")
    #else
        #pragma comment (lib, "Release/HTUSB.Lib")  
    #endif

#endif

#ifdef  _MSHID_
    // use to include head files and link MS library file.
    #include "MSAPI.h"
#endif


// Return codes
#define     HT_SUCCESS                  0x00
#define     HT_READ_ERROR               0x01
#define     HT_WRITE_ERROR              0x02
#define     HT_INVALID_PARAMETER        0x03
#define     HT_INVALID_REQUEST_LENGTH   0x04
#define     HT_SYSTEM_ERROR_CODE        0x05
#define     HT_READ_TIMEOUT             0x06
#define     HT_WRITE_TIMEOUT            0x07
#define     HT_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND         0xFF

// USB Connect/Disconnect function 
HIDDLL_API DWORD WINAPI HTUSB_Open(WORD wPID, WORD wVID);
HIDDLL_API DWORD WINAPI HTUSB_Close();
HIDDLL_API BYTE WINAPI HTUSB_GetDeviceCount();

// USB Rx/Tx function 
HIDDLL_API DWORD WINAPI HTUSB_WriteCmd(DWORD dwSize,BYTE *pBuf);
HIDDLL_API DWORD WINAPI HTUSB_ReadCmd(DWORD dwSize,BYTE *pBuf);
HIDDLL_API DWORD WINAPI HTUSB_WriteData(DWORD dwSize,BYTE *pBuf);
HIDDLL_API DWORD WINAPI HTUSB_ReadData(DWORD dwSize,BYTE *pBuf);
HIDDLL_API DWORD WINAPI HTUSB_WriteEvent(DWORD dwSize,BYTE *pBuf);
HIDDLL_API DWORD WINAPI HTUSB_ReadEvent(DWORD dwSize,BYTE *pBuf);
HIDDLL_API DWORD WINAPI HTUSB_WriteCmdI(int index,DWORD dwSize,BYTE *pBuf);
HIDDLL_API DWORD WINAPI HTUSB_ReadCmdI(int index,DWORD dwSize,BYTE *pBuf);
HIDDLL_API DWORD WINAPI HTUSB_WriteDataI(int index,DWORD dwSize,BYTE *pBuf);
HIDDLL_API DWORD WINAPI HTUSB_ReadDataI(int index,DWORD dwSize,BYTE *pBuf);
HIDDLL_API DWORD WINAPI HTUSB_WriteEventI(int index,DWORD dwSize,BYTE *pBuf);
HIDDLL_API DWORD WINAPI HTUSB_ReadEventI(int index,DWORD dwSize,BYTE *pBuf);

HIDDLL_API DWORD WINAPI HTUSB_SetTimeouts(DWORD ReadTimeout, DWORD WriteTimeout);
HIDDLL_API DWORD WINAPI HTUSB_GetTimeouts(LPDWORD ReadTimeout, LPDWORD WriteTimeout);

// USB Information function
HIDDLL_API BOOL WINAPI HTUSB_GetManufacturerID(USHORT *pBuf);
HIDDLL_API BOOL WINAPI HTUSB_GetProductID(USHORT *pBuf);
HIDDLL_API BOOL WINAPI HTUSB_GetDeviceVersion(USHORT *pBuf);
HIDDLL_API BOOL WINAPI HTUSB_GetManufacturerString(PVOID  Buffer, ULONG  BufferLength);
HIDDLL_API BOOL WINAPI HTUSB_GetProductString(PVOID  Buffer, ULONG  BufferLength);
HIDDLL_API BOOL WINAPI HTUSB_GetManufacturerIDI(int index,USHORT *pBuf);
HIDDLL_API BOOL WINAPI HTUSB_GetProductIDI(int index,USHORT *pBuf);
HIDDLL_API BOOL WINAPI HTUSB_GetDeviceVersionI(int index,USHORT *pBuf);
HIDDLL_API BOOL WINAPI HTUSB_GetManufacturerStringI(int index,PVOID  Buffer, ULONG  BufferLength);
HIDDLL_API BOOL WINAPI HTUSB_GetProductStringI(int index,PVOID  Buffer, ULONG  BufferLength);

HIDDLL_API BOOL WINAPI HTUSB_GetSerialNumberString(PVOID pBuffer, ULONG  BufferLength);
HIDDLL_API BOOL WINAPI HTUSB_GetSerialNumberStringI(int index,PVOID pBuffer, ULONG  BufferLength);
HIDDLL_API BOOL WINAPI HTUSB_FlushQueue();
HIDDLL_API BOOL WINAPI HTUSB_FlushQueueI(int index);

HIDDLL_API BOOL WINAPI HTUSB_Test();

HIDDLL_API BOOL WINAPI HTUSB_ReplugHIDDevice(char *szVen,char *szProd);











#endif  // __USB_TRUBO_H__
```

And lastly: here's a picture link to my folder structure: [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTPHQ.jpg)

**I am essentially trying to write to a HID device, and this was the dll that came with the device to allow for that communication. Any help would be appreciated**

Comment: Pleaase it is important to note that I am using vscode